# Creating a simple rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to transform this:

```
http://example.com/hot-apps
```

to this:

```
http://example.com/hot
```

This is the rule that I use:

```
RewriteRule ^hot-apps$ iphone/hot
```

But it doesn't work?. Why, and what would be the solution?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to `iphone/hot` or to `/hot`? The usage of .htaccess file on the server could be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^hot-apps$ hot
```

That `iphone/` is the issue.

Comment: The imstake was with using the symbol ^ before the keyword..no idea why it mattered